# AWS Aurora MySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, auto-increment, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to migrate to Aurora MySQL and having problems with auto increment. With Aurora MySQL:

```
create table test (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,Primary Key(id));
insert into test (id) values(0);
insert into test (id) values(0);
insert into test (id) values(0);
update test set id=100 where id=3;
select * from test;
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
|   1 |
|   2 |
| 100 |
+-----+
insert into test (id) values(0);
select * from test;
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
|   1 |
|   2 |
|   4 |
| 100 |
+-----+

With MySQL or MariaDb the last result is: 

+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
|   1 |
|   2 |
| 100 |
| 101 |
+-----+
```

Notice that Aurora MySQL "fills" the gap where as MySQL maintains a max and uses that.

Can I configure Aurora MySQL to maintain the same auto increment behavior? If so, how?

Comment: Mariadb version is 5.5.65-MariaDB. Aurora MySQL is 5.7.mysql_aurora.2.07.2

Answer (score 0):

After migrating the table you can change the auto increment value.

The syntax is a bit convoluted because it is not possible to directly use a query or a variable with `ALTER TABLE ... AUTO_INCREMENT` but this is how you would proceed:

```
SET @maxid = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM test);
set @sql = concat('ALTER TABLE test AUTO_INCREMENT = ', @maxid + 50);
prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

You can play with it with this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3cc7fd61087a2b91649ff02bb29fec2b)

Comment: I don't think OP is as concerned with the exact value of the increment, but the fact that it's acting like a row with ID #3 is still there, and *might* act like a row of ID #100 is *not* there. When it gets to 100, there may be a key conflict. (Needs testing.)

Comment: @ceejayoz I agree at ID 100 it would conflict. Clearly aurora does not change the auto increment when he does `update test set id=100 where id=3;`, if he wants to do that he would need to adjust the auto increment manually as shown, I don't think there is another clear path

Comment: Yep, the issue is the numbers generated are different between the systems for the exact same sql sequence. Really a non starter for our app that may have dependencies with the behavior in this area. App has 1000's of lines of SQL. Not practical to rewrite.

Comment: @user44021 Assuming auto increment IDs will be consistent between infrastructures is not a good idea; you might run prod on a multi-master cluster, for example, where IDs may skip a few here and there due to auto_increment_offset. Don't assume that. I'm indeed curious about whether Aurora will have an issue here when it gets to #100, but that'll be an Aurora bug. What you're describing is a coding mistake.

Comment: Not a coding mistake. We use product A, then try to switch to product B which reports to produce the same results as A given the exact same input. In this case it doesn't hence the issue, The issue came up in our units tests. We do 1000's of these. One test fails because of this. It is contrived, not actually something in our app so we are moving forward with Aurora anyway....